# wso2 bam2.4 connect to external cassandra failed

Tags: cassandra, wso2, wso2-bam

I am using wso2 bam 2.4.0 connecting with a standalone cassandra 1.2.13 in the same machine for testing.
At first I started the cassandra instance with no issue, then configured bam to connect to this external cassandra.
Cassandra use the default settings, and I change cassandra-component.xml like this:

```
<Cassandra>
<Cluster>
    <Name>Test Cluster</Name>
    <DefaultPort>9160</DefaultPort>
    <Nodes>localhost:9160</Nodes>
    <AutoDiscovery disable="false" delay="1000"/>
</Cluster>
```

Then start bam using this command:

```
sh wso2server.sh -Ddisable.cassandra.server.startup=true
```

then I see this exception:

> [2014-01-01 11:28:44,201] ERROR
>   {org.wso2.carbon.core.init.JMXServerManager} -  Could not create the
>   RMI local registry java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in
>   use: 9999; nested exception is:   java.net.BindException: Address
>   already in use    at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.listen(TCPTransport.java:310)  at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.exportObject(TCPTransport.java:218)
>     at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.exportObject(TCPEndpoint.java:393)
>     at sun.rmi.transport.LiveRef.exportObject(LiveRef.java:129)

I don't know what I am missing, but sure the port is conflicting. can someone point it out?

Answer (score 0):

RMI Registry port 9999 is already in use by another process. That's why you are getting this exception. First confirm which process is using it by using 'netstat -antp | grep 9999' command. You can do one of the following things to avoid getting this error.

- Set port 'Offset' to a different value in BAM_HOME/repository/conf/carbon.xml
- Set 'RMIRegistryPort' to a different value in BAM_HOME/repository/conf/carbon.xml
- Stop RMI server from starting by setting 'StartRMIServer' to false in BAM_HOME/repository/conf/etc/jmx.xml